# Filling spinner in different thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-spinner

Im trying to fill a spinner in my application in a different thread. Can somoene tell me why the following code is not working?

The following code is in the oncreate() method

```
Thread asyn = new Thread(){
       public void run(){
           try{
               int klok = 0;
               while(klok < 5000){
                   sleep(100);
                   klok = klok + 100;
               }

                try{



                   String[] items = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
                  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Materiaal.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
                  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                  spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);



                    }catch(Exception ex){
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

           }catch(InterruptedException ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
    };

    asyn.start();
```

Comment: what is the issue you are having? are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the method runOnUiThread(Runnable r) from the Activity.

Maybe do something like this

```
void run()
{
    // do stuff
    .
    .
    .
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

         void run()
         {
             spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
         }

     );
}
```

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting View touched from wrong thread exception.

When you want to perform any UI operation from other than the main thread, you should use runOnUi(YOUR_RUNNABLE).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the error you're having is because you can't update the UI via other thread that isn't the UI thread.

To accomplish what you want, you should use AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), do your work in the `doInBackground()` method and finally update your interface in the method `onPostExecute()`.